# Select XML from varchar(max) column

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have some XML data stored in a varchar(max) column on SQL Server 2005. The data is in the form (FQTN = fully qualified type name):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<History xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <EntityViews>
    <EntityProxy Type="FQTN" Key="386876" />
    <EntityProxy Type="FQTN" Key="387981" />
    <!-- etc. -->
  </EntityViews>
</History>
```

How can I select Type, Key so that I get a tabular result from the XML data in this column for a single row? The table has an identity primary key named HistoryId.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to make the column `XML` data type and us XPath?

Comment: Probably but this is not new development. I created the table and I don't remember if we were on 2005, 2000, or Oracle at the time. How I should have done it is a different question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
;with cteCastToXML as (
    select CAST(YourColumn as xml) as x
        from YourTable
)
select h.ep.value('@Type','varchar(10)') as [Type],
       h.ep.value('@Key', 'varchar(10)') as [Key]
    from cteCastToXML
        cross apply x.nodes('/History/EntityViews/EntityProxy') as h(ep)
```

Comment: Thanks! The only substantial change I had to make was that YourColumn needs to be cast as nvachar(max) before casting as xml because the encoding is utf-16.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be two fold.

1. If this is what you will be doing with the column, change the column to be an XML column.
2. If you need to do this one time, look at taking the value and converting it to XML, then you can operate on it like you would normally.  (Here is a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) on how to convert).