# SQL Query - Querying XML, having issues

Tags: sql, xml

I'm working on a project and need some help trying to get this XML query to work.  I'm trying to query the XML below in SQL as a new column "Company" with the Company values.

The column name is `CustomData` and is varchar(3000) so it looks like it needs to be converted to XML, unless there is another way to do this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ArrayOfCustomData xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <CustomData name="Company" value="WT001" />
   <CustomData name="Location" value="123456" />
   <CustomData name="DealerCode" value="WT" />
   <CustomData name="Domain" value="WT" />
   <CustomData name="Region" value="1234" />
</ArrayOfCustomData>
```

Here is the SQL code I'm using.

```
select CustomData.value('(/ArrayOfCustomData/CustomData name="Company")[1]','varchar(30)') as Company
from tbl_User_Ref
```

I get this error:

> "Cannot find either column "CustomData" or the user-defined function or aggregate "CustomData.value", or the name is ambiguous."

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This may be obvious to you, but how do you expect it to find the column "CustomData"? Was the XML snippet in a column named as such?

Comment: Yeah that's the name of the column as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working by using the code below.  Not sure why but it looks like my XML is actually UTF-16 and not UTF-8, which might've been giving me problems as well.  Thanks for the help.

```
CAST(CAST(CustomData AS NTEXT) AS XML).value('(/ArrayOfCustomData/CustomData[@name="Company"]/@value)[1]','varchar(3000)') as Company
```

Answer (score 2):

Your XPath is invalid, try this way instead :

```
select 
    CustomData.value('(/ArrayOfCustomData/CustomData[@name="Company"]/@value)[1]','varchar(30)') as Company
from tbl_User_Ref
```

Notice the use of `@` at the beginning of attribute name to address an XML attribute, and the use of expression within square-brackets (`[....]`) to filter XML data (to filter `<CustomData>` by value of `name` attribute to be specific).

**UPDATE :**

If you're using SQL Server you can use `CAST()` function to convert the column to XML type, for example :

```
select 
    (CAST(CustomData as xml)).
            value('(/ArrayOfCustomData/CustomData[@name="Company"]/@value)[1]','varchar(30)') as Company
from tbl_User_Ref
```

### [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7d894/1)

Another approach using CTE : [Select XML from varchar(max) column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429568/select-xml-from-varcharmax-column)

Comment: I tried this but I'm still getting the same error message.  CustomData.value is underlined in red but everything else seems fine.  Is there something else that should be added?

"Cannot find either column "CustomData" or the user-defined function or aggregate "CustomData.value", or the name is ambiguous."

Comment: It looks like the column CustomData isn't even XML, it's varchar(3000), so I think it needs to be converted to XML first and then queried.

Comment: I tried the query again with the new code you added and now I get "XML parsing: line 1, character 39, unable to switch the encoding"  I feel like I'm getting closer..

Comment: @user3460072 that can happen if you cast from a *varchar* string with UTF-16 encoded XML or if you cast from *nvarchar* where you have UTF-8 encoded XML. In the question you say the column is varchar and the XML is UTF-8 so that should work just fine. Perhaps your column is nvarchar or you have a mix of UTF-16 and UTF-8 encoded XML.

Answer (score -1):

DECLARE @DocHandle int

DECLARE @XmlDocument nvarchar(1000)

SET @XmlDocument = N'please put your Query(XML)'

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @DocHandle OUTPUT, @XmlDocument

SELECT *
FROM OPENXML (@DocHandle, '/ArrayOfCustomData/CustomData',1)
      WITH (name  varchar(10),
            value varchar(20))

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @DocHandle